# Ask the duck - how to disable it?

Tags: support

Today a yellow duck started popping up in the bottom right corner of the browser window. I can hide it through an adblocker option, but is there an option to disable this feature in user/profile settings?

[image: Ask Ubuntu page with duck offering help]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308570/how-do-i-disable-quack-overflow-i-hate-this-duck-button-is-only-temporary

Comment: The solution supposed into the related topic - works. Thank you, @MarkKirby!

Comment: You could ask the duck how to do that .